# What is the "@anaconda" repo in the output from "yum list installed"?

Tags: centos, yum

In the output of a `yum list installed`, I got

```
wget.x86_64              1.14-13.el7     @base               
which.x86_64             2.20-7.el7      @anaconda
```

But `anaconda` is not in the list of repositories.

I suspect the repository was defined at installation time, but I can not confirm this.

Answer (score 22):

The anaconda repository is not really a repository. It just means that when you installed CentOS, those packages were also installed during the installation. [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(installer)) is the installer program CentOS uses.